# Visual Studio Code C/C++ Include Path not working for custom header files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm writing with C using VSC and MinGW GCC. I can include default headers like these:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
```

However, when I create my own header file in the subdirectory "Source", let's say it's name is "Test.h", if I try to include it, **there is no error in VSC**, only when I try to compile with GCC (by typing gcc Main.c -o Test.exe) do I get the error that says this:

```
Main.c5:10: fatal error: test.h: No such file or directory. 
  #include "test.h"
```

Here is my c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/Source"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**As well as this,**

Whenever I compile and this error occurs, if I open up "test.h", I get this error **in VSC**:

https://prnt.sc/1hxct6g  (screenshot)

If I follow this error, it opens up my C/C++ configuration, and tells me to edit my includePath settings.

I've tried multiple things, none have worked. Any help?

Comment: "*However, when I create my own header file in the subdirectory "Source", let's say it's name is "Test.h", if I try to include it*" - If you have really named it **Test.h** and not **test.h**, then you should do: `#include "Test.h"`

Comment: @Yochran - let us know if correcting the case for the header name solved the problem so this question can be closed. If it did not, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Changing from "test.h" to "Test.h" has not fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your include path is (where your header files are): `"${workspaceFolder}/Source"`

If you run your compiler from within your workspace folder then you have to add the `-I` option to the command line:

```
gcc -ISource Main.c -o Test.exe
```

**More info**: [GCC - Search Path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)